Event log source is not created after publishing a .NET Core 8 web site
I am using Logger to log errors in my web application. It works perfectly in my development machine but not when published.
This error is logged in the event log (using Application source):

Unable to log .NET application events. The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique. Inaccessible logs: Security, State.


How can I add the source? am I missing some permission?
EDIT:
This is register as error:


May I know if you have got any chance to check my reply? It will be great if you can share more detailed information for us to better investigate this issue. Thanks for your cooperation.

It's a classic permission issue, you need to check the official document first.
Fail to write to the Windows event log from an ASP.NET or ASP application
According to the error message, we need to make sure the source is exist in your server.
The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

The information above should help you fix it, if not, please follow below steps to add/modify CustomSD.
1. Create a custom user account in your server, and change the identity in application pool.

2. Run below command to get username and sid.
wmic useraccount get name,sid

3. Add a CustomSD and Copy the sid and apply it.
O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x3;;;<SID>)(A;;0x3;;;BU)
OR (according to your needs)
O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x3;;;<SID>)(A;;0xf0002;;;BG)


